# How to Compress/Decompress tar.gz files in java

Tags: java, gzip, tar, compression

Can anyone show me the correct way to compress and decompress tar.gzip files in java i've been searching but the most i can find is either zip or gzip(alone).

Comment: tgz files aren't anything special -- you un-gzip it first, then un-tar it.

Comment: related: [How to print the content of a tar.gz file with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094074/how-to-print-the-content-of-a-tar-gz-file-with-java)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315618/how-do-i-extract-a-tar-file-in-java

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My favorite is plexus-archiver - see sources on [GitHub](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-archiver).

Another option is Apache [commons-compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) - (see [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.2)).

With plexus-utils, the code for unarchiving looks like this:

```
final TarGZipUnArchiver ua = new TarGZipUnArchiver();
// Logging - as @Akom noted, logging is mandatory in newer versions, so you can use a code like this to configure it:
ConsoleLoggerManager manager = new ConsoleLoggerManager();
manager.initialize();
ua.enableLogging(manager.getLoggerForComponent("bla"));
// -- end of logging part
ua.setSourceFile(sourceFile);
destDir.mkdirs();
ua.setDestDirectory(destDir);
ua.extract();
```

Similar *Archiver classes are there for archiving.

With Maven, you can use this [dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-utils/3.0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
  <artifactId>plexus-archiver</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 44):

I've written a wrapper for [commons-compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) called [jarchivelib](http://rauschig.org/jarchivelib/) that makes it easy to extract or compress from and into `File` objects.

Example code would look like this:

```
File archive = new File("/home/thrau/archive.tar.gz");
File destination = new File("/home/thrau/archive/");

Archiver archiver = ArchiverFactory.createArchiver("tar", "gz");
archiver.extract(archive, destination);
```

Comment: This is great - this works the same way a command line utility would - unzip <archive> <destination>, abstracting all boilerplate details from me (perhaps if I needed to worry about performance I'd use the commons-compress library, but I nearly never have to).

Comment: @thrau : Its gives me a compile time error as : The method createArchiver(String, String) is undefined for the type String

Comment: and add cast to archiver

Comment: have a look at the other examples on the web page http://rauschig.org/jarchivelib/examples.html

Comment: @thrau Is there any callback for file extraction ? I want to know once the extraction is done.

Comment: @madhuriHR `extract` is blocking and will return once extraction is complete, no callback required

Answer (score 18):

To extract the contents of .tar.gz format, I successfully use **apache commons-compress** ('org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12'). Take a look at this example method:

```
public void extractTarGZ(InputStream in) {
    GzipCompressorInputStream gzipIn = new GzipCompressorInputStream(in);
    try (TarArchiveInputStream tarIn = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzipIn)) {
        TarArchiveEntry entry;

        while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry) tarIn.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            /** If the entry is a directory, create the directory. **/
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                File f = new File(entry.getName());
                boolean created = f.mkdir();
                if (!created) {
                    System.out.printf("Unable to create directory '%s', during extraction of archive contents.\n",
                            f.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } else {
                int count;
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entry.getName(), false);
                try (BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER_SIZE)) {
                    while ((count = tarIn.read(data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                        dest.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Untar completed successfully!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using the try-with-resources syntax, you shouldn't need `dest.close();` and `tarIn.close();`

Comment: Warning: This is unsafe due to ZipSlip, do not use this code in production software. Specifically f.mkdir() is not safe to call in the blind: https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability

Comment: Useful to additionally note that the ZipSlip vulnerability mentioned by sichinumi can be avoided by skipping (or rewriting) any file names (or the whole archive) which contain directory traversal portions "../" or "./" as they are usually a pretty clear-cut sign of something malicious.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience [Apache Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) is much more mature than [Plexus Archiver](http://plexus.codehaus.org/plexus-components/plexus-archiver/), specifically because of issues like http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXCOMP-131.

I believe Apache Compress has more activity as well.

Comment: Apache Compress cannot extract some tar.gz archives because of a lack of support. This bug has never been resolved : https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-651

Comment: @didile how do you expect this to get fixed if the bug was reported to jfrog instead of apache compress?

Comment: It has been also reported to apache issue tracker.

Comment: @didile please provide a link.

Comment: @didile I don't see any bug reported to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COMPRESS that would match HAP-651. It would be great if you could open one and attach a tar where Compress fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to compress/decompress **on Linux**, you can call the shell command line to do that for you:

```
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(target));
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("sh", "-c", String.format("tar xfz %s -C %s", tarGzPathLocation, target));
builder.directory(new File("/tmp"));
Process process = builder.start();
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
assert exitCode == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

With [TrueVFS](http://truevfs.net/) extracting Tar.GZip archive is one-liner:

```
new TFile("archive.tar.gz").cp_rp(new File("dest/folder"));
```

But beware of [dependencies issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160554/how-to-reduce-truevfs-dependencies).