# How to extract tgz file in windows using java

Tags: java, ubuntu, compression

Is there any way where tgz file which is been `compressed in Ubuntu OS` can be extracted in windows using java.
My code works properly if the files are been compressed in windows. But if the files are compressed in ubuntu then its not extracting properly. DO anyone knows solution for this

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128171/how-to-compress-decompress-tar-gz-files-in-java

Comment: i tried this but not working

Comment: This could be due to encoding differences, did you try commons-compress ? http://java-tweets.blogspot.sg/2012/07/untar-targz-file-with-apache-commons.html