# Groovy script to create tar.gz file

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to create tar.gz file using Groovy, but i couldn't find a way. Please let me know if there is any way in Groovy.

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apache commons-compress library.

See [How to Compress/Decompress tar.gz files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128171/how-to-compress-decompress-tar-gz-files-in-java)

Anything that works in Java will also work in Groovy; it's just not as Groovy.